# How to read two words at a time from file in python

Tags: python

I have a file "test.txt" which has below info

```
hiii hello
how r
good bye
```

i would like to know how to read two words at same time ??

Below is my code to read word by word

```
f1 = open("test.txt","r+")


for k in f1.read().lower().split():
    print "\n word" + k
```

Comment: do you want to read a line at a time?

Comment: Clearly not your actual code, since the unclosed quote wouldn't make it past the parse step...

Comment: read a line and then split it.

Comment: is that you're trying to iterate over every two elements?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question, you want to fetch every two words at each iteration. Use `next()` to an iterator. Don't forget to handle `StopIteration` exception.

```
with open("test.txt","r") as f1: 
    data=iter(f1.read().split())

while True:
    try:
        a= next(data)
        b= next(data)
        print a,b
     except StopIteration:
        print "No more pair"
        break
```